# Как установить kde 4 в fedora 22

Tags: linux, kde, fedora

Использую *spin KDE Plazma 5 Fedora 22*. Есть несколько критичных багов, которые мешают работе.

Как установить *kde* версии 4?

Я думал это "плевое дело", но весь гугл забит статьями как перейти с 4 на 5 версию и то все для *fedora 21*.

Единственное решение которое я нашёл и относилось к *fedora 22 beta*

```
dnf group install kde4
```

Не работает.

Есть ли возможность перейти обратно на 4 ветку?

Кстати, в репозитории я мало вижу программ *kde4* версии -их вынесли куда-то в другой репозиторий теперь?

Comment: *Не работает* ­— это не описание ошибки. приведите, пожалуйста, подробности, отредактировав вопрос кнопкой [edit]

Comment: @alexander barakin Написал не работает, потому что это вообще не решение. Просто раньше когда-то на уровне бетты было. Выдает Warning: Group 'kde4' does not exist. По сути все поменяли и куда-то перенесли, но как сейчас называются репы, какими командами устанавливаются - не понятно, везде только plazma 5 по дефолту ставиться.

Comment: ну, удалили группу. но пакеты-то вряд ли куда-то делись  из репозитория. я бы попробовал установить ту же группу с помощью `yum` — не исключено, что мета-информация у этих пакетных менеджеров несколько отличается. если и у него группа не описана, попробуйте какие-нибудь базовые пакеты устанавливать — они за собой «потянут» зависимости. что-нибудь вроде kde-base* или в том же духе. kdm какой-нибудь.

Comment: Попробывал отдельно через yum - не работает. Пакеты тоже не тянутся, если что-нибудь из 4 ставить. Сейчас если 5 ставить то просто каша из версий по программам если смотреть есть и 15.04, и 4.XX различных версий и просто где-то в пакетах вижу plazma 5. Может быть есть какой-то способ поставить полностью рабочий стол для 4 kde? По кускам не получается собрать - монстр выходит. Такое ощущение, что сейчас ситуация как с 3 kde - только отдельный дистрибутив брать или Trinity ставить ( Не хочется Fedora менять, привык к ее пакетам уже...

Answer (score 1):

если из мета-информации, которой обладает программа `dnf`, удалили группу *kde4*. то пакеты-то вряд ли куда-то делись из репозитория.

предлагаю попробовать установить ту же группу с помощью `yum` — не исключено, что мета-информация у этих пакетных менеджеров несколько отличается.

если и у него группа не описана, попробуйте какие-нибудь базовые пакеты устанавливать — они за собой «потянут» зависимости: что-нибудь вроде *kde-base* (или что-то в том же духе, *kdm* какой-нибудь).

**обновление**

если ничего из предложенного не помогает, в запасе остаётся как минимум два варианта:

1. переустановить ту версию дистрибутива, в которой были удобные для вас пакеты.
2. путь тернистый и без гарантии успеха: [подключить репозиторий](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) с пакетами для требующейся версии дистрибутива и [устанавливать из него нужные пакеты нужной вам версии](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151690/110559).

Comment: @alexanderBarankin kdm к сожалению тянет за собой всего 9 пакетов ( kde-base сейчас нет

Comment: @DenisSavenko, я обновил ответ.

Comment: @alexanderBarankin, попробую такой путь, но странно что так быстро выкинули все 4 пакеты(

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь человек поддерживает репозитории для установки KDE4 на Fedora 22/23/24: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/peem/kde4-fedora/

У меня ноутбук тоже уже не может осилить Plasma 5 (тормозит загрузка и графика). А репозитории Fedora 21, на которой я сейчас, на иностранных серверах уже подчищают. Надо переходить на Fedora 24 с KDE4 и ждать, когда доделают Plasma.

Обсуждение: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/kde/2015-October/016245.html

И еще: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=307148